# Android Menu with submenu animated effect

Tags: android, menu, submenu

I need to create sub menu of menu.When I click on menu then sub menu should display as below image attached and when I click on Adjustment menu ,then it should open sub menu.
[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.phone:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.computer:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Computer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.gamepad:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Gamepad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.camera:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.video:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    case R.id.email:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected EMail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    }
    return true;        
}
```

menu xml

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:title="phone"
        android:icon="@drawable/phone"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/computer"
        android:title="computer"
        android:icon="@drawable/computer"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/gamepad"
        android:title="gamepad"
        android:icon="@drawable/gamepad"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:title="camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/camera"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:title="video"
        android:icon="@drawable/video"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:title="email"
        android:icon="@drawable/email"
        myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />

</menu>
```

Comment: here is image url http://android.digitzmedia.com/com.database_test/menu.png

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Give us the code you already have and where you're stuck so we can be able to help you ;)

Comment: i have posted code also..please check url of image that i want it